# Angular 2/4 Animating Host Component using Host Bindings, is it possible?

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I'm trying to fade out a component from the component itself. I don't know if this is possible, I'm trying to achieve this using a `HostBinding`.

**Animations:**

```
animations: [
    trigger('fade', [
        state('fadeIn', style({ opacity: 1 })),
        state('fadeOut', style({ opacity: 0, visibility: 'hidden' })),
        transition('* <=> *', [
            animate(250)
        ])
    ])
]
```

**Host Binding:**

```
HostBinding('@fade') animateComponent(state: string) {
    return state;
}
```

The example I have is a loading overlay which is a separate component. When the loading service triggers that the loading is complete I'm trying to fade out the component.

**Plunker Example:** https://plnkr.co/edit/heNSZYNJErXnF8bxaCiz

I'm not sure if the animations I've set up are incorrect or else this cannot be achieved with the use of `HostBinding`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of thing wrong with your plunker:

1. You have to import the `BrowserAnimationsModule` from `@angular/platform-browser/animations` in your `AppModule`.
2. You're missing the `@` in the `HostBinding` decorator.
3. `@HostBinding` basically lets you bind some value (which could change in the lifecycle of your component) to the host element, and that is your component itself. So you have to bind to a class property rather than a method.

Here's a working version of your [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4Zjh0cQhHpxIeT8SOItD)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I guess I was in a bit of a hurry when I wrote the code in plunker. As you pointed out my mistake in my code is that I'm trying to bind to a method rather than a property. Thanks for your help :)